# Why does this not concatenate two strings?

Tags: c, loops, c-strings, function-definition, strcat

This is the requirement for my code:

> This function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string, overwriting the terminating null byte (`'\0'`) at the end of `dest`, and then adds a terminating null byte.
>
> Returns a pointer to the resulting string `dest`.

This is the output I am getting:

```
Hello
World!
Hello World!
Hello
```

Here is my code:

```
char *_strcat(char *dest, char *src) {
    int lengthd = 0;
    int lengths = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    char tmp[10];
    while (dest[i] != '\0') {
        lengthd++;
        i++;
    }
    while (src[k] != '\0') {
        tmp[lengths] = src[k];
        lengths++;
        k++;
    }
    for (; j < lengths - 1; j++) {
        dest[lengthd + 1] = tmp[j];
    }
    dest[lengthd + 1] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}

int main(void) {
    char s1[98] = "Hello ";
    char s2[] = "World!\n";
    char *ptr;
    printf("%s\\n", s1);
    printf("%s", s2);
    ptr = _strcat(s1, s2);
    printf("%s", s1);
    printf("%s", s2);
    printf("%s", ptr);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Where are `s1`, `s2`, and `ptr` defined?

Comment: edited now, i added the definition of s1, s2 and ptr

Comment: `lengths++; tmp[lengths] = src[k];`. That skips index 0 in `tmp`.

Comment: i made `tmp[lengths] = src[k]` on top but still the same output

Comment: `while (src[k] != '\0') {` <<-- for() loops exist for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails for multiple reasons:

- you use a temporary array to make a copy of the source string: this array `tmp` has a fixed length of 10 bytes, which is too small if the source string is longer than 10 bytes. Otherwise you will have undefined behavior when you write beyond the end of this array.
- there is really no need for this temporary array anyway.
- the final loop stops at `lengths - 1`, hence you stop before the last byte of the copy.
- you copy all bytes to the same position `dest[lengthd + 1]`.
- you finally set the null terminator at the same position again.
- you never changed the null terminator at `dest[lengthd]` so the function appears to have no effect on `dest`.
- the tests in `main()` cannot produce the output you posted, probably because of a typo in `"%s\\n"`.
- avoid using identifiers starting with an `_`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *my_strcat(char *dest, char *src) {
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    /* find the offset of the null terminator in dest */
    while (dest[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
    /* copy the bytes from the src string there */
    while (src[k] != '\0') {
        dest[i] = src[k];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    /* set the null terminator */
    dest[i] = '\0';
    /* return the pointer to the destination array */
    return dest;
}

int main(void) {
    char s1[98] = "Hello ";
    char s2[] = "World!";
    char *ptr;
    printf("%s\n", s1);
    printf("%s", s2);
    ptr = my_strcat(s1, s2);
    printf("%s", s1);
    printf("%s", s2);
    printf("%s", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the source string is not modified and the offsets should have type `size_t` and can be incremented as a side effect of the assignment:

```
char *my_strcat(char *dest, const char *src) {
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t k = 0;

    /* find the offset of the null terminator in dest */
    while (dest[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
    /* copy the bytes from the src string there */
    while (src[k] != '\0') {
        dest[i++] = src[k++];
    }
    /* set the null terminator */
    dest[i] = '\0';
    /* return the pointer to the destination array */
    return dest;
}
```

You can also use pointers instead of offsets:

```
char *my_strcat(char *dest, const char *src) {
    /* use a working pointer to preserve dest for the return value */
    char *p = dest;

    /* find the offset of the null terminator in dest */
    while (*p != '\0') {
        p++;
    }
    /* copy the bytes from the src string there */
    while (*src != '\0') {
        *p++ = *src++;
    }
    /* set the null terminator */
    *p = '\0';
    /* return the pointer to the destination array */
    return dest;
}
```

One final change: you can combine reading the source byte, copying to the destination and testing for the null terminator, which will have been copied already:

```
char *my_strcat(char *dest, const char *src) {
    /* use a working pointer to preserve dest for the return value */
    char *p = dest;

    /* find the offset of the null terminator in dest */
    while (*p != '\0') {
        p++;
    }
    /* copy the bytes from the src string there */
    while ((p++ = *src++) != '\0') {
        /* nothing */
    }
    /* the null terminator was copied from the source string */
    /* return the pointer to the destination array */
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: everything is so clear now , many thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

At least due to the declaration of the character array `tmp` with the magic number `10`

```
char tmp[10];
```

the function does not make a sense.

Moreover in this while loop

```
  while (src[k] != '\0')
  {
          lengths++;
          k++;
          tmp[lengths] = src[k];
  }
```

the first element of the array `tmp` is skipped.

Also in this for loop

```
  for (; j < lengths-1; j++)
  {
          dest[lengthd + 1] = tmp[j];
  }
```

the condition of the loop is incorrect. Also the expression `dest[lengthd + 1]` skips the terminating zero character of the string pointed to by the pointer `dest`. And all characters are written at the same position `lengthd + 1`.

Apart from this the names `s1`, `s2` and `ptr` used in main were not declared.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
char * my_strcat( char *dest, const char *src )
{
    char *p = dest;

    while ( *p ) ++p;

    while ( ( *p++ = *src++ ) != '\0' );

    return dest;
}
```

and can be called like

```
char s1[13] = "Hello ";
const char *s2 = "World!";

puts( my_strcat( s1, s2 ) );
```

Another way to define the function using an approach similar to yours is the following

```
char * my_strcat( char *dest, const char *src )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( dest[i] != '\0' ) ++i;

    for ( size_t j = 0; src[j] != '\0'; j++ )
    {
        dest[i++] = src[j];
    }

    dest[i] '\0';  

    return dest;
}
```

Comment: it works thank you!, but i want to understand ur code can you elaborate the function you wrote pleaseee

Comment: @Natnaelk What is unclear?

Comment: @Natnaelk After this loop while ( *p ) ++p; the pointer p points to the terminating zero of the string dest.. This loop while ( ( *p++ = *src++ ) != '\0' ); copies all characters from src to the dest starting from the terminating zero of dest until the zero character '\0' in the source string is assigned to dest.

Comment: i got the idea but i still can't read this code, can you use a biginner friendly code please

Comment: @NatnaelkSee my appended answer.